# When base controller is initialized in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a web application in MVC 2 that employs a base controller for all other controllers to reduce initialization of controllers to one place. The base controller contains properties like menu, current user etc. Here is the code:

```
public class BaseController : Controller 
{
    private Common.MenuHierarchy _menu;
    private User _currentUser;

    internal NavMenuViewModel Menu(string pageId)
    {
        bool isGuest = this.CurrentUser.GroupProfileId == Constant.SecurityGroupProfile.Public;

        if (this._menu == null)
        {
            this._menu = CreateMenu();
        }
    }

    internal User CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._currentUser == null)
            {
                this._currentUser = CreateUser();
            }

            return this._currentUser;
        }
    }
}
```

All other controller derive from BaseController. For example,

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
   ...
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
   // Display home page
   ...
}
```

I notice that after directed to Home index, the _currentUser property has been initialized. But if I set point break inside get, it won't stop there. I wonder when base controller is initialized. Thanks.

Comment: Are you caliing `Menu()` from anywhere? It seems unlikely that `currentUser` would be initialized if it isn't.

Comment: Yes, Menu() is called. currentUser is initialize before it is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Home controller is being built it starts from the Base controller CTOR and the `_currentUser` is being initialized, after that the HomeController CTOR is taking place. The reason it doesn't stop in the getter is, that there is no one that gets the `CurrentUser`. The initialization is seperated from the getter.

Comment: I think _currentUser is initialized null when Home controller is created. The CreatUser is called only when get is called for currentUser. But CreatUser is called when Home controller is created (or after 1st command in Index() is executed), which is weird.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is actually being initialized when your HomeController constructor is being called. BaseClass constructor is first being called then derived class constructor. So in your case it's BaseController constructor then HomeController constructor. Although you dont define constructor in BaseController it is still doing it. So answer to you question BaseController is being initialized when HomeController is created.

UPDATE:

If you want to know when actions and other properties are being called try adding this to methods or properties:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This will be displayed in output window");
```

While you are debugging you can see which are being called and in what order.
This can help you to understand when CurrentUser is being initialized.

Comment: Yes, I know it is being initialized when HomeController constructor is being called. In this case, I think _currentUser is initialized null when Home controller constructor is being called, and CreatUser is called only when get is called for currentUser. But I notice that after 1st command in Index() in Home controller, _currentUser is created already which means that get in CurrentUser is run when Home controller constructor is called. What do you think, Jon?

Comment: Hmm it shouldn't unless you call it in Index() action or I'm wrong.